# Twilio Programmable Chat - not able to run the quickstart project

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

I was trying to run  twilio quickstart code for programmable chat, but I was getting the below error.

Logging in...
There was an error creating the chat client:
Error: Fetch resource from "Client/v1/Configuration" failed.
Please check your .env file.

configurations seems proper in Twilio Server Starter Kit Environment Setup.

[image]

[image]

Adding Few more information as requested.

I don't have a code for now, I am testing my api for conversation using postman, I am trying to read the the list of messages using postman, but I get authentication error, just wanted to know the format of request body to pass the credential.

[image]

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the terminal where the server is running? (As a note, the [programmable chat service is being sunset in July](https://www.twilio.com/changelog/programmable-chat-end-of-life) and you should use the [Conversations API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations) instead.

Comment: Thanks..! In that can you please send me any reference quickstart project from twilio for using conversation api, I am planning to have front end in angular and the server in C#.net for my chat application, any reference example will make my job easier...

Comment: I linked to the documentation, there are quick start applications there, I'm sure you can find them.

Comment: Thanks @philnash, that helped, I could create a conversation, add participants and send messages, but when i try to retrieve the list of message sent, I get unauthorized response, can you please let me know what is the format I should pass my authorization, 

url -https://conversations.twilio.com/v1/Conversations/CHXXXXX/Messages
body - {
 "Authorization": "ACXXXXXXXXXXX:eXXXXXXXXXXX"
}

response - 
,
    "detail": "Your AccountSid or AuthToken was incorrect.",
    "message": "Authentication Error - No credentials provided",
    "status": 401

Comment: Can you update your question with the full code you're using? I can use that to write a proper answer for you.

Comment: @philnash, added the requested information, can you please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To authenticate the API request properly in Postman you need to add your Account SID and Auth Token (or [API Key and secret](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-is-an-api-key)) as the username and password for Basic Auth under the Authorization tab.

[image]

Comment: it worked, I could get the message list.....! Thanks for your time and support.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it!